# Where should my users folder be in a Slim 3 project?

Tags: php, slim

I'm currently building a simply file hosting script using Slim 3. Currently I have my users folder on the same level as my public directory. Now that I'm attempting to access the files inside the user folder I'm getting errors caused by my document root not being able to access my users folder. Would it be a better idea to put my users folder inside my public folder because technically that would be public info to the logged in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what these files are - If they are only for the specific user or if they are available to all users.

When the files has to be private you can not put them into public, simple because everyone could hack url and get access to them. So you should put them in any `data` directory and make them available using an endpoint like `/file/{username}/{name}`.

In such endpoint you can easily append Header about filetype or if it should download or try to show in the browser window.

Comment: I ended up creating a route file that takes the logged in users username and params from the url. Works perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: But you should be sure that users only has access to their own files, if they don't share them.

Comment: The actual path doesn't show for example `username/file` it just shows the file to be downloaded and the folder it is in under the users folder. The username part of the file to be downloaded is being loaded dynamically via PHP, the user never sees this and has no way to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you make publicly available to the web server will be handled by default as any other asset:

- Its URL is based upon the actual file name
- If you know the URL you can download it
- If it's a `.php` file it will be executed

You can certainly address all this concerns (and some of them may not even be concerns for your use case) but I don't think this is the ideal layout for a typical user-managed directory tree. Your current approach makes more sense to me.

To access such files you need to create a proper download script that makes all the appropriate checks (e.g. access checks), matches file system stuff from URLs and serves the assets as static files. In Slim that means creating a route with parameters and writing a handler function that does all this stuff.